# YoutubeLiveの配信開始を検知するwebhookは存在するのか？

Tags: youtube

Youtube Liveの配信開始を検知する仕組みを実装しようと試みており、YouTube Live Streaming APIのドキュメントを閲覧しているのですが、タイトルの内容を実現する為のwebhook的なものが見当たりませんでした。

もしご存知の方が居られましたらご教示頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

私の知る限り、2018年12月現在 API として公開されているものには生放送が開始されたことをプッシュ通知してくれる仕組みは無いです。["Add pubsub capability to notify when a channel goes live"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36124161) という issue はあるのですが、解決していません。

[`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=ja) や [`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) を使えば「いま生配信しているか」は分かりますが、通知にするにはポーリング等をしないといけません。また経験上、配信を開始した直後ほんの数分は上手く取得できない気がします [要出典]。

#### 関連質問

- [Get notification from Youtube API when a channel starts live?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49530549/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- [Is there a way to get notifications from YouTube API when broadcaster is live](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46558476/5989200) -- Stack Overflow